# Objeto para Array php

Tags: php

Olá, estou com um problema, este código abaixo esta retornando um objeto de 'tipo', preciso que 'tipo' seja array.

```
while ($obj = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $stmt2 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM wines a, uva b WHERE a.id_tipo = '.$obj['idtipo'].' AND a.id_uva = b.id GROUP BY a.id_uva');
       while ($obj2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
             $wines[$obj['tipo']][] = $obj2;
       }

}
```

Ele retorna assim

```
{"ESPUMANTES": [
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "MIOLO MILESSIME",
        "uva": "BRUT"
    },

],
"VINHOS BRANCOS": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "CASA VALDUGA LEOPOLDINA GRAN RESERVA",
        "uva": "CHARDONNAY"
    },

]}
```

preciso que "ESPUMANTES" e "VINHOS BRANCOS"  esteja dentro de um array.

```
{
[
   1: "ESPUMANTES" [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "CASA VALDUGA LEOPOLDINA GRAN RESERVA",
            "uva": "CHARDONNAY"
        }
    ] 
],
[
    2: "VINHOS BRANCOS" [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "CASA VALDUGA LEOPOLDINA GRAN RESERVA",
            "uva": "CHARDONNAY"
        }
]
```

}

Comment: Se eu entendi direito. Você quer que fique assim: `array("ESPUMANTES", "VINHOS BRANCOS")`. É isso?

Comment: basicamente isso, mas dentro de cada um outro array com as informaçōes

Comment: Para cada vinho ele pode ter mais de uma categoria? É isso?

Comment: Exemplo... MIOLO MILESSIME pode ser "ESPUMANTES" e "VINHOS BRANCOS". É isso?

Comment: Você poderia mostrar o resultado final desejado?

Comment: algo parecido com isso, por que preciso iterar la no angular com ngFor os tipos de vinhos que são ESPUMANTES ou VINHOS BRANCOS, em uma lista que abre um modal com os vinhos em si.

Comment: Entendi. Vou postar uma resposta e você ve se dá certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
$x = 0;
while ($obj = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $stmt2 = $db->query('SELECT * FROM wines a, uva b WHERE a.id_tipo = '.$obj['idtipo'].' AND a.id_uva = b.id GROUP BY a.id_uva');
    while ($obj2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $wines[$x][$obj['tipo']] = $obj2;
    }
    $x++;
}
```

Comment: iiisssoo meu querido! hahaha, muito obrigado por me ajudar, e ajudar a comunidade que vai ter essa duvida no futuro, estou enrolado neste projeto a um tempo pois não sou bom com php valeu!! <3

Comment: XD tranquilo! As vezes é difícil entender o problema por isso demoramos um pouco. Mas é isso ai. Boa Sorte!

Answer (score 0):

Aparenta ser um JSON estes dados

Tenta:

```
$array = json_decode($objeto, true);
```

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Patrick, se você não ter a necessidade de ser dentro do PHP a transformação para array, pode fazer da seguinte forma.

Onde eu atribui o valor para x, seria no caso a response do teu servidor.

```
let x = {
"ESPUMANTES": [
    {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "MIOLO MILESSIME",
        "uva": "BRUT"
    }
],
"VINHOS BRANCOS": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "CASA VALDUGA LEOPOLDINA GRAN RESERVA",
        "uva": "CHARDONNAY"
    }
],
"VINHOS TINTOS": [
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "ERRAZURIZ 1870 RESERVA CARMENERE ",
        "uva": "CARMENERE"
    }
]
};

let z = Object.values(x);
z.forEach(res => { console.log(res) });
```